# angular $http attach default promises

Tags: angularjs

Goodmorning,

i wanted to know if there's a way to attach by default a promises, i'll explain better....

```
module.factory('serviceName', function($http) {
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

return {
        call1: function(callback) {
            return $http.post('url1/something').then(callback);
        },
        call2: function(param1, param1, callback) {
            return $http.post('url2/something', $.param({param1: param1, param2: param2, })).then(callback);
        }
    };
});
```

this is basically my service and i would like to know if there's a way of chaining a promise at the end of each of this call using something like  $http.default.something
this would be really helpful :D

Comment: `$http.post` already returns a promise.  And this promise can already be chained.  What is the question?

Comment: yeah i know that. Ok i need to chain another THEN after the first one, and because i'm a bit lazy, i just wanted to know if i can define somewhere that after the first promise attach another one for every call in my service (without manually doing it)

Comment: Yes, you can do this. You just have to return another promise inside the first `then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there's a way of chaining a promise

**Yes**,

- You can chain promises to create code flows
- One of advantages: Error propagates, so you can catch it on the end of the 
  chain

*Reference how chain promises works*

[image]

About your example:

I don't think its a good way to use `callback` when `$http.post` returns promise itself.

If you want to create factory return promise, you can write:

```
         var request = function(data) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        var configHttp = {
                                method: 'POST',
                                url: 'some URL'
                        };
                        if (data !== undefined) {
                                configHttp.data = data;
                        }
                        $http(configHttp).success(function(data, status, headers) {
                                if (data.error === undefined) {
                                        deferred.resolve(data);
                                } else {
                                        deferred.reject(data);
                                }
                        }).error(function(data, status, headers) {
                                deferred.reject(data);
                        });
                        return deferred.promise;
                }
               return {
                    call1: function(param1) {
                            return request('get_1', {param: param1});
                    },
                    call2: function(param2) {
                            return request('get_2', {param: param2});
                    }
```

So in controller we can write:

```
 serviceName.call1..then(function(result)
 {               
              //....

   }, function(error) {
     alert(error.message);
   });
```